How to debug gpupdate?
My gpupdate can take upto 10 minutes to run instead of 40s.
How can I debug gpupdate ? :
PS C:\> ~/psh/time.ps1 gpupdate
Updating policy...

Computer Policy update has completed successfully.
User Policy update has completed successfully.


=> The processing took 00:10:00.42.


PS C:\>


Group Policy environment debug logging. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/a-treatise-on-group-policy-troubleshooting-8211-now-with-gpsvc/ba-p/400304

The 10 minutes delay could indicate hitting the script timeout. Should be in the log though.
